# "File", "Edit" etc. Will Not Show Up On Cinnamon Desktop Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: ubuntu, cinnamon, window

I recently switched to the cinnamon desktop on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am wondering why the window options such as "File" and "Edit" aren't showing up at the top of my windows. Occasionally they show up on the gnome Terminal or Files, but that's it. What's going on?

"File" and "Edit" etc. won't show up on Firefox:

[image: "File" and "Edit" etc. won't show up on Firefox]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are talking about chrome browser, please add "chrome" in the title.  If you are asking for generally all applications, please do not accept the answer below: it solves the problem only for chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> for the menu to appear. If you want the menu to appear at all times, enable View > Toolbars > Menu bar.